# Does Genesis Framework provide any benefits with headless WP setup?

Tags: wordpress, headless, genesis, headless-cms

Are there any advantages of using Genesis framework if we use WordPress for the backend only? In a headless setup with either Angular or React, I was wondering if there would be any advantages of using it.

Thanks...

Comment: Never heard of it (clicks link) "Why the Open Source Genesis framework is the Foundation of Any Smart WordPress Design". (scrolls down) $59.95 ? How is that open source?

Comment: This is going to be primarily opinion based and not a good question for Stack Overflow. Voted to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it will help a bit because it has very well organized software architecture with multiple API levels for non-developers, but it's mainly for front end client UI manipulation. Angular or React are much better choices if you have the skills.